# SAS: Removing first and last characters and numbers of a string

Tags: sas, substr

I am searching for hours but nothing seems to work so far. I tried reverse, substr and scan but it's all not doing what I need. I am so thankful for any answer.

I have a string in a following way (lenghts vary in the dataset):

1CDF534R6

Now, I need 2 new variables:

a) 534, i.e. the middle numbers
Something like: Give me all numbers and then cut the first and last (that would work in my case).

b) 1CDF536
Just removing the last two characters

Especially the first one is important and would be great if it works somehow. 
Best

Comment: SCAN & SUBSTR both work perfectly for me. Please post the code you've tried explaining what isn't working.

Comment: I will just add one line to above solution to cut first and last character from the string. e = substr(source, 2, 7);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case use a `compress` function. Keep only digits.

```
data result;
    source = "1CDF534R6";
    a = compress(source, , 'kd');
    a = substr(a, 2, lengthn(a) - 2);

    b = substr(source, 1, lengthn(source) - 2);
run;
```

Comment: That was not the question tho